# How can we get request values from body in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I want to write design document that contain views, and in the view i need to get values from body. I done like this in couchdb using list. But i don't know how to achieve the same in couchbase.

Currently i write the value in view directly.

```
`function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.name!='anoop'){
  emit(doc.name, [doc]);
  }
}`
```

I need to replace that value by getting through body.

Comment: me also need same solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couchbase does not support lists, only views. and you cannot pass vales to the mapper just because at the query performed to after index built and stored to the disk

you can try N1QL http://www.couchbase.com/communities/n1ql